# Weird flask server crash and database error when making HTTP request

Tags: python, http, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask route for getting a list of all users:

```
@app.route('/api/user/get_users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    return user.get_users(request)


def get_users(self, request):
    users = fdb.read("""SELECT * FROM _users""", (), True)
    return jsonify({
        "allUsers": users
    })
```

`fdb.read` is just an abstraction of the following code:

```
def read(self, query_string, query_params = (), fetchall = True):
    try:
        data = self.connection.execute(query_string, query_params)
        if fetchall: 
            data = data.fetchall()
            data = [dict(row) for row in data]
        else:
            data = data.fetchone()
            data = dict(data)
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return e
    finally:
        pass
```

And here is my connection method:

```
def connect_flask_sql_alchamy(self, engine_name, user, password, host, database):
    uri = engine_name + "://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host
    self.engine = create_engine(uri)
    self.engine.execute("USE "+database)
    self.connection = self.engine.connect()
    self.connection_type = FLASK_SQL_ALCHEMY
```

Which works just fine when I go and make a request from by browser or Postman. But if i use Axios/fetch or any other xhr HTTP request tool, I get a set of results. The result is - it doesnt work but what is weird is that with the same request i get different errors each time, and some times the local flask server will just abruptly crash with no error message after this route is hit.
Here is the most common error I saw:

```
Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dimo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1375, in _safe_close_cursor
    cursor.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 86, in close
    while self.nextset():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 139, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2020 10:09:14] "GET /api/general/get_general_data HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I also got a few of these:

```
(MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1046, 'No database selected')
[SQL: SELECT * FROM _users]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I'm currently keeping the connection opened all the time. Could that be the cause of this? I had a few suspicions that i might need to call `commit()` on the connection and then close the connection after each `C/R/U/D` method but the fact that it crashed the flask server means that something doesnt add up. Ive never had code that would do such a thing. Whenever I had a database connection or query error, the error was always cought and printed.

Comment: Okay so I have done a bit more testing and it appears as if this error will occur whenever there is a lot of traffic hitting the REST API regardless of which route i'm requesting.
I have never experienced such error in any language (PHP, Node or Python). Any suggestions?

Comment: "I'm currently keeping the connection opened all the time" - this is probably not a good idea.  It might be better to create a new connection for each request, and close it once the request has completed.

Comment: I tried it that way too, saw similar results. However after playing around with pooling (changing pool size) it has improved and doesn't seem to give the error. Id still like to keep testing before I add the answer.

BTW I am actually trying to create a dynamic connection opening/closing to save on server time and performance - keep connection open for 10 minutes, if there is no new connection in those 10 minutes then close connection, if there is a new connection, set timer back to 10 minutes. I played around with this concept and saw around 5% performance improvement on the test i wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently an "engine" is a whole pool of connections and my usage of the "use" statement will only take effect for one of those connections - not all.

To get around this, I connected to the database through the URI instead of executing a `use Database` command:

```
uri = engine_name + "://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/" + database
```

instead of:

```
uri = engine_name + "://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host
self.engine = create_engine(uri)
self.engine.execute("USE "+database)
```

That solved my issue of the failed database connection. The server crash was actually caused by something else - me returning an exception and them trying to JSON serialize it. Instead i raised an exception this time and it stopped crashing.